# filtering an array based on multible conditions react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to filter an array based on multiple conditions. these conditions are based on a switch and the problem is if i toggle one switch the state changes to true and i get the required result, but if i toggle two or more switches at the same time as shown in the image i get an empty array. I want to get an array with the true values of the toggled switches and discard all the false values in the MEALS array

[image]

this is the switch screen

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import AnimatedLoader from "react-native-animated-loader";
import { ScrollView, Switch } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
const Switch= ({navigation})=>{

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [hasMeatCube, setHasMeatCube] = useState(false);
    const [hasGroundMeat, setHasGroundMeat] = useState(false);
    const [hasKofta, setHasKofta] = useState(false);
    const [hasLiver,setHasLiver] = useState(false);
    const [hasSusage, setHasSusage] = useState(false);
    const [hasMeatShank, setHasMeatShank] = useState(false);

 const startLoading = ()=>{
        setLoading(true)
        setTimeout(()=>{
            navigation.navigate('FilteredList',{filteredList: {
                hasMeatCube, 
                hasGroundMeat,
                hasTurkey,
                hasKofta,
                hasLiver,
                hasSusage,
            }})
            setLoading(false)
        },3000)
    }

return(
        <View style={ styles.container }>
            <View style={styles.findRecipe}>
                <ScrollView>
                    <Text style={ styles.title }> البروتينات - اللحوم </Text>
                    <View>
                    <View style={styles.switchView}>
                        <Text>مكعبات لحمة</Text>
                        <Switch value={hasMeatCube} onValueChange={newValue=> setHasMeatCube(newValue)} />
                    </View>
                    
                    <View style={styles.switchView}>
                        <Text> لحمة مفرومة </Text>
                        <Switch value={hasGroundMeat} onValueChange={newValue=> setHasGroundMeat(newValue)} />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.switchView}>
                        <Text>كفتة</Text>
                        <Switch value={hasKofta} onValueChange={newValue=> setHasKofta(newValue)} />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.switchView}>
                        <Text>كبدة</Text>
                        <Switch value={hasLiver} onValueChange={newValue=> setHasLiver(newValue)} />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.switchView}>
                        <Text>سجق</Text>
                        <Switch value={hasSusage} onValueChange={newValue=> setHasSusage(newValue)} />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.switchView}>
                        <Text> موزة لحمة </Text>
                        <Switch value={hasMeatShank} onValueChange={newValue=> setHasMeatShank(newValue)} />
                 
                </ScrollView>
                <View>
            <AnimatedLoader
                visible={loading}
                overlayColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.75)"
                source={require("../../assets/SearchRecipe.json")}
                animationStyle={styles.lottie}
                speed={1}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.submit}
                onPress={ startLoading }
            >
                <Text>يلا</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>       
            </View>  
        </View>
    );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  
});

export default Switch;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {MEALS} from '../../data/RecipiesData'



const FilteredList = ({navigation, route})=>{

  
    const {filteredList} = route.params
    const data = MEALS.filter(meal => {
        if(filteredList.hasMeatCube && !meal.hasMeatCube){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasGroundMeat && !meal.hasGroundMeat){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasTurkey && !meal.hasTurkey){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasKofta && !meal.hasKofta){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasLiver && !meal.hasLiver){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasSusage && !meal.hasSusage){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasMeatShank && !meal.hasMeatShank){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasEscalop && !meal.hasEscalop){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasCheckin && !meal.hasCheckin){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasCheckinFillet && !meal.hasCheckinFillet){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasKidney && !meal.hasKidney){
            return false
        }
        if(filteredList.hasCabbage && !meal.hasCabbage){
            return false
        }
        return true;
```

this is the model

```
class Meal {
  constructor(
    id,
    categoryIds,
    title,
    imageUrl,
    flag,
    duration,
    calories,
    servings,
    ingredients,
    steps,
    hasMeatCube,
    hasGroundMeat,
    hasTurkey,
    hasCabbage,

  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.categoryIds = categoryIds;
    this.title = title;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.flag = flag;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.calories = calories;
    this.servings = servings;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.steps = steps;
    this.hasMeatCube = hasMeatCube;
    this.hasGroundMeat = hasGroundMeat;
    this.hasTurkey = hasTurkey;
    this.hasCabbage = hasCabbage;


  }
}

export default Meal;
```

and this is the MEALS array

```
import Meal from '../model/Meal';

export const MEALS = [
    new Meal('m1',['c1', 'c12'], 'كفتة', 
        [
            '../assets/Egyptian_Kofta.jpg',
            '../assets/Egyptian_Kofta2.jpg',
        ],
        'EG',
        45,
        1250,
        4,
        [
            '1 كيلو لحمة مفرومة',
            '1 بصلة مفرومة',
            '1 صفار بيضة',
          
        ],
        [
            'وضع اللحمة والملح والفلفل في بولة',
            'اضافة صفار البض والاوريجانو',
        
        ],
        false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,
        false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
 
        ),
    new Meal('m2',['c9', 'c13'], 'فراخ مشوية بالكرات', 
        [
            '..assets/Grilled_Chicken_Leeks_.jpg',
            '..assets/Grilled_Chicken_Leeks_1.jpg',
 
        ],
        'JP',
        25,
        4,
        750,
        [
            'نص كيلو افخاد دجاج مخلية بالجلد',
            'ملح وفلفل اسود',
            'صويا صوص',
 
        ],
        [
            'تقطيخ الفخاد لقطع صغيرة ',
            'نتبلها بالملح والفلفل',
            'نضيف الصويا على الفراخ',
  
        ],
        false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,
        false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,
 

    ),
    new Meal('m3', ['c4', 'c13'], 'فراخ تندوري',
    [
        '../assets/Tandoori_.jpg',
        '../assets/Tandoori_1.jpg',
    ],
    'IN',
    60,
    4,
    1200,
    [
        'فرخة مقطعة منزوعة الجلد',
        'ربع كوب عصير ليمون',
        'فصين ثوم مفرومين',
    ],
    [
        'نقطع الفرخة ارباع ونعمل فتحات بالسكينة علشان تتبل مكويس',
        'نحط التوابل والزبادي في الخلاط لغاية ما نعمل منهم معجون',
    ],

    false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,
    false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
    ),

    new Meal('m4',['c5', 'c14'], 'جمبري مشطشط بالكرفس والكاجو',
    [
        '../assets/Spicy_Shrimp_Celery_.jpg',
        '../assets/Spicy_Shrimp_Celery_1.jpg',
    ],
    'CN',
    15,
    4,
    500,
    [
        'كيلو جمبري مقشر',
        'بصل اخضر مقطع',
        'معلقة صويا صوص',
        'معلقة زيت سمسم',
        'معلقة هل ابيض',
    ],
    [
        'نخلط الصويا صوص مع الخل وزيت السمسم',
        'نضيف الزنجبيل والثزوم والشطة',
        'نسخن طاسة تيفال لمدة دقيقتين',
    ],

    false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
    false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,

    ),
];
```

Comment: Add the meal array please

Comment: i added the MEALS array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I can't recreate a react environment here. Instead I have built the object `route`, so I can filter the `MEALS` array (OP provided in his update) according to the checked switches as defined in `route.params.filteredList`:

```js
// testing environment:
const route={params:{filteredList:{
 hasGroundMeat:1, hasCabbage:1}}};

class Meal {
 constructor(id,categoryIds,title,imageUrl,
  flag,duration,calories,servings,ingredients,steps,
  hasMeatCube,hasGroundMeat,hasTurkey,hasCabbage) {
   this.id = id;
   this.categoryIds = categoryIds;
   this.title = title;
   this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
   this.flag = flag;
   this.duration = duration;
   this.calories = calories;
   this.servings = servings;
   this.ingredients = ingredients;
   this.steps = steps;
   this.hasMeatCube = hasMeatCube;
   this.hasGroundMeat = hasGroundMeat;
   this.hasTurkey = hasTurkey;
   this.hasCabbage = hasCabbage;}
}
const MEALS=[new Meal('m1',['c1', 'c12'], 'كفتة', 
    [
        '../assets/Egyptian_Kofta.jpg',
        '../assets/Egyptian_Kofta2.jpg',
    ],
    'EG',
    45,
    1250,
    4,
    [
        '1 كيلو لحمة مفرومة',
        '1 بصلة مفرومة',
        '1 صفار بيضة',
      
    ],
    [
        'وضع اللحمة والملح والفلفل في بولة',
        'اضافة صفار البض والاوريجانو',
    
    ],
    false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,
    false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
 
    ),
new Meal('m2',['c9', 'c13'], 'فراخ مشوية بالكرات', 
    [
        '..assets/Grilled_Chicken_Leeks_.jpg',
        '..assets/Grilled_Chicken_Leeks_1.jpg',
 
    ],
    'JP',
    25,
    4,
    750,
    [
        'نص كيلو افخاد دجاج مخلية بالجلد',
        'ملح وفلفل اسود',
        'صويا صوص',
 
    ],
    [
        'تقطيخ الفخاد لقطع صغيرة ',
        'نتبلها بالملح والفلفل',
        'نضيف الصويا على الفراخ',
  
    ],
    false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,
    false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,
 

),
new Meal('m3', ['c4', 'c13'], 'فراخ تندوري',
[
    '../assets/Tandoori_.jpg',
    '../assets/Tandoori_1.jpg',
],
'IN',
60,
4,
1200,
[
    'فرخة مقطعة منزوعة الجلد',
    'ربع كوب عصير ليمون',
    'فصين ثوم مفرومين',
],
[
    'نقطع الفرخة ارباع ونعمل فتحات بالسكينة علشان تتبل مكويس',
    'نحط التوابل والزبادي في الخلاط لغاية ما نعمل منهم معجون',
],

false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,
false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
),

new Meal('m4',['c5', 'c14'], 'جمبري مشطشط بالكرفس والكاجو',
[
    '../assets/Spicy_Shrimp_Celery_.jpg',
    '../assets/Spicy_Shrimp_Celery_1.jpg',
],
'CN',
15,
4,
500,
[
    'كيلو جمبري مقشر',
    'بصل اخضر مقطع',
    'معلقة صويا صوص',
    'معلقة زيت سمسم',
    'معلقة هل ابيض',
],
[
    'نخلط الصويا صوص مع الخل وزيت السمسم',
    'نضيف الزنجبيل والثزوم والشطة',
    'نسخن طاسة تيفال لمدة دقيقتين',
],

false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,
false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,

),
];
// console.log(MEALS);

// actual filtering part for your React environment:
const ingredients="MeatCube,GroundMeat,Turkey,Kofta,Liver,Susage,MeatShank,Escalop,Checkin,CheckinFillet,Kidney,Cabbage".split(",").map(e=>"has"+e)
const fl = route.params.filteredList;
const data = MEALS.filter(meal =>
  // ingredients.some(ing=>fl[ing]&&meal[ing])
     ingredients.every(ing=>!fl[ing]||meal[ing])
)
console.log(data.map(d=>d.id+": "+d.title).join(","));
```

The way the MEALS array is created seems overly complicated to me and it is also flawed in a way that only the first four Boolean `has...`-ingredients arguments are picked up in each `new Meal()` instantiation call. The remaining 14 Boolean arguments are completely ignored.

Please not that I changed the filtering method too. In the `MEALS.filter()` callback function you will find two variants:

```
 // ingredients.some(ing=>fl[ing]&&meal[ing])
    ingredients.every(ing=>!fl[ing]||meal[ing])
```

The first one (commented out) requires *at least one* ingredient of `filteredList` to be in a `meal` while the second one requires *all* of the selected ingredients to be in it.

Comment: can you please check the edits I made. I will be gratfule if oyu can assist me i am still learning react native and javascript and i don't know how to figure this out.

Comment: I changed my answer to include your MEALS array.